# How to read filenames in segments to retrieve a set of files in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a set of files in the below format in two different directories.

```
LS-2bit_a0_c0_apple_p1.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_apple_p1.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_apple_p2.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_apple_p2.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_mango_p1.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_mango_p1.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_mango_p2.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_mango_p2.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_grape_p1.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_grape_p1.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_grape_p2.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c0_grape_p2.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_apple_p1.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_apple_p1.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_apple_p2.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_apple_p2.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_mango_p1.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_mango_p1.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_mango_p2.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_mango_p2.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_grape_p1.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_grape_p1.txt  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_grape_p2.log  
LS-2bit_a0_c1_grape_p2.txt
```

and the sequence follows for c0,c1,c2 etc. I want to read the files by segment and perform an operation each set of files individually. (eg.retrieve all files with C0_apple alone.But it outputs all apple files (eg. c0_apple,c1_apple, C2_apple...)

I am very new to batch script and tried the below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\windows\system32
for /f %%a in ('dir /on /ad /b') do (
    cd %%a
    for %%b in (LS-2bit*) do (
        call :fun1
    )
    :fun1
    for %%b in (*a0*) do (
        call :fun2
    )
    :fun2
    for %%b in (*C0*) do (
        call :fun3
    )
    :fun3
    for %%b in (*apple*) do (
        call :fun4
    )
    for %%b in (*p1.log, *p1.txt, *p2.log *p2.txt) do (
        echo %%b
    )
    cd..
)
```

Sorry for not being very clear. Here is exactly what I need to do. it is a huge set of data. I need to group each set (eg. c0_apple_*, c1_apple, c2_apple, c0_mango, c1_mango,c2_mango and so on like nearly 15 set groups of fruits). each set contains 4 log files(p1,p2,p3,p4) and 4 text files(p1,p2,p3,p4). I need to retrieve average value from log file and rate value from the text file and store them in a seperate file.(log file value and text file value can be in the same output file) so each set (c0_apple has one output file, c1_apple has one output file...). I worked on retreiving value with the below function in my old code.

```
`for %%b in (*p1* *p2*) do(

    type %%b | find " bit " >> new1.txt
    )
    for /f "tokens=3" %%d in (new1.txt) do (
    echo %%d > temp.txt
    for /f "delims=." %%r in (temp.txt) do (
    echo | set /p = %%r %tab% >> hmlog.txt
    del temp.txt
    )
    )
```

`and`

```
for %%b in (*p1* *p2*) do(
type %%b | find "Average" >> new.txt
)
for /f "tokens=2" %%b in (new.txt) do (
echo %%b  >> hmtxt.txt
)`
```

However, the question now is, since the data is huge is there a way to loop through the folder to get each set of data and generate the output file during each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: The original request in this question was changed, so I need to change my solution accordingly. However, clear specifications about the new problem were not posted, so I need to *guess* the specifications that I will use to develop my new program. Here they are:

- In a directory there is a set of files with this name format:

  `LS-2bit_a0_c#_fruit_p#.txt`

  `LS-2bit_a0_c#_fruit_p#.log`

where `LS-2bit_a0` part is fixed; `c#` part vary as c0, c1 and c2; `fruit` part vary over 15 different groups of fruits (like "apple", "mango", "grape", etc.); and p# part vary from p1 to p4.

- The *.txt files have several lines each, including one with a rate value in this format:

  `Rate bit ###.##`
- The *.log files have several lines each, including one with an average value in this format:

  `Average ###`
- The program must group data from the 4 *.txt files and the 4 *.log files that correspond to the same `c#_fruit` combination and store them in the same output file with `c#_fruit.out` name. Each output file must have these two lines:

  `RateP1 RateP2 RateP3 RateP4`

  `AvgeP1 AvgeP2 AvgeP3 AvgeOP4`

... where RateP# is the integer part of the number after "bit" in *.txt files, and AvgeP# is the number after "Average" in *.log files; the values must be separated by a TAB character.

The program below fulfills **these** specifications:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Group rate data from 4 *.txt files in its corresponding "c#_fruit.out" output file
set "i=0"
set "line="
for /F "tokens=3,4,8 delims=_. " %%a in ('findstr /C:" bit " *.txt') do (
   rem Insert here v a TAB character
   set "line=!line! %%c"
   set /A i+=1
   if !i! equ 4 (
      > %%a_%%b.out echo !line:~1!
      set "i=0"
      set "line="
   )
)

rem Group average data from 4 *.log files in its corresponding "c#_fruit.out" output file
for /F "tokens=3,4,6 delims=_ " %%a in ('findstr "Average" *.log') do (
   rem Insert here v a TAB character
   set "line=!line! %%c"
   set /A i+=1
   if !i! equ 4 (
      >> %%a_%%b.out echo !line:~1!
      set "i=0"
      set "line="
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> type *.out

c0_apple.out


123     456     789     987
111     222     333     444

c0_mango.out


123     456     789     987
111     222     333     444

c1_apple.out


123     456     789     987
111     222     333     444

c1_mango.out


123     456     789     987
111     222     333     444
```

Comment: Thank you. I quite understood how this works. I shall try this and revert back.

Comment: This works absolutely fine! Could you also assist on how to iterate on two segment values in for loop? Like C0 and apple together?

Comment: Wow! So this is a question where you will change the specifications each time that the previous request was completed? Sorry, but I don't work this way! I need a _precise description_ of the whole problem, a small example of the input data and the desired output based on such data. Don't use terms like "huge data" that means nothing, but exact numbers. Don't post extensive lists of similar data; it is enough with a small section and a _clear explanation_. Also, you should realize that posting a code segment is _not_ a substitute for a description, specially if the code don't works...

Comment: Sorry for piling up multiple requests and unclear description. You got the problem statement perfectly right. Your new answer was exactly what I was looking for. Worked just the way it has to.Thanks a ton.

Comment: In such a case you should set the check-mark in my answer and later, when you have enough rep to do so, upvote it. This is the method we use to say "Thanks"...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /on /ad /b "%sourcedir%"') do (
    PUSHD "%sourcedir%\%%a"
    DIR /b /a-d *LS-2bit*a0*c0*apple*p*.log *LS-2bit*a0*c0*apple*p*.txt
    echo \\\\
    for %%b in (*LS-2bit*a0*c0*apple*p1*.log *LS-2bit*a0*c0*apple*p1*.txt
            *LS-2bit*a0*c0*apple*p2*.log *LS-2bit*a0*c0*apple*p2*.txt) do (

     ECHO %%b
    )
    echo ++++
    for %%b in (LS-2bit) do (
     for %%c in (a0) do (
      for %%d in (C0) do (
       for %%e in (apple) do (
        for %%n in (p1 p2) DO FOR %%x IN (log txt) do (
     IF EXIST "%%b*%%c*%%d*%%e*%%n.%%x" ECHO(%%b*%%c*%%d*%%e*%%n.%%x
    )
        echo ----
        for %%n in (p1 p2) DO FOR %%x IN (log txt) do (
     DIR /b /a-d "%%b*%%c*%%d*%%e*%%n.%%x"
    )
        echo ====
    PAUSE
       )
      )
     )
    )
    POPD
)
ECHO done
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

It's not really clear what you want to do.

Block statements `(a parenthesised series of statements)` don't play nicely with labels as a label terminates a block.

Using a string containing `*` or `?` in a `for` loop makes the string into a filename - to use the string literally, you need to first enclose it in quotes like `"*c0*"` and then when it's assigned to a metavariable `%%X`, extract it using `%%~X`.

There seems to be little point in using the fixed text `LS-2bit`, `a0`, `c0`, `apple` etc. You don't explain what your batch is intended to do, so we're off to guesswork territory. Perhaps you could run this as a subroutine where these elements would be supplied as parameters (in which case, replace each of the fixed strings with `%~1`, `%~2` etc.

Here's four different ways to produce a filelist. Don't know which you'd prefer...

Comment: This worked! But as i have updated my question, could  also assist in checking if this can be looped for all sets? the total variations in names are for (c0, c1, c2) and about 15 fruit names for each. LS-bit, a0 and p names are same throughout.

Comment: Assuming you're using the methods below `echo ++++` then it's a simple as adding the extra data items into the list, so `for %%d in (C0)...` becomes `for %%d in (C0 C1 C2)...` and `for %%e in (apple)...` becomes `for %%e in (apple grape mango)...`

Comment: This works for log files, but somehow the text files are not retrieved. "file not found" error pops up and I double checked the file exists in the directory.

Comment: Worked happily for me. Please post your current code by editing it into your question. There's no charge for questions, so please don't extend the question - ask another if required. Also, in your latest posted code you **must** have a space between `do` and `(`